# php Scope Variable from Differents files in class

Tags: php, scope

I can't acces to the variable create un a specific file and using by another link by a third one.
Here is an example, I have 3 files:

testing.php

```
<?php 
$special ="foo";
?>
```

other.php

```
<?php
echo $special; // that works

class Testing
{
   public function toto()
   {
     echo $special;//Error considering as undefined
   }
}
?>
```

main.php

```
<?php
require 'testing.php';
echo "require work $special";// that works
require 'other.php';

$a = new Testing();
$a->toto();//error
?>
```

So how can i acces to my variable `$special` in the member of my class Testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $special variable is not visible from within the function. For that to work, you need to pass the function the $special variable as an argument when you call it.